# Tailwind CSS doesn't work with Material UI in Next 14.0.2

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I'm using Next 14.0.2 with Material UI and Tailwind CSS for the Frontend development.
Currently I'm facing some issues with styling components.
I set the button to navigate to the sign up form using Link(next/link) component.

[image]

[image]

```
<Link
  href={"/user/register"}
  className="transition-all text-gray-200 hover:text-white"
>
  Register
</Link>
```

When I click the button, it is navigated to Register page. But when I navigate using Link, the Register page doesn't compile all Tailwind CSS styles specially margin styles like my-2, mx-4 and so on. Here you can take a look at the 1st screenshot attached.
But when I go to Register page directly by specifying page URL on the browser or refresh the page after it is navigated, it worked as the 2nd screenshot shows.

It should also work when I navigate to the register page by clicking Link component, not only directly going to the page URL. Here is some of my code for the register page.

```
<TextField
   label="First Name"
   variant="outlined"
   className="w-full md:w-44 my-2"
   {...register("firstName")}
   error={errors.firstName ? true : false}
   helperText={errors.firstName?.message}
 />

 <TextField
  label="Middle Name"
  variant="outlined"
  className="w-full md:w-40 md:mx-4 my-2"
  {...register("middleName")}
  error={errors.middleName ? true : false}
  helperText={errors.middleName?.message}
/>

<TextField
  label="Last Name"
  variant="outlined"
  className="w-full md:w-44 my-2"
  {...register("lastName")}
  error={errors.lastName ? true : false}
  helperText={errors.lastName?.message}
/>
```

And this is my tailwind.config.ts file

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/client/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

export default config;
```

I've shared the CodeSandbox link for the better understanding.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-jang-5vhkd4

Would like to get help with this issue encountered.

Comment: Could you share a CodePen (or similar)? So you can more easily demonstrate the problem (screenshots are fine, but it's important to be able to replicate in an easily shareable format)

Comment: Sure, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-jang-5vhkd4